# MySql GenerationType.AUTO does not generate anything and returns 'Field doesn't have a default value'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following code which should auto-generate user_id (PK) in the table USER. However, when adding data to the table I get the error: *ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value*. On the other hand, when I do manually insert bigInt there is no problem and the data is added to the table, however this is not the point and I want it to be automatically generated. Can someone help me find out what is wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Comparable<User>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="username", unique=true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name="firstname", nullable =false)
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="middlename", nullable =true)
    private String middlename;
    @Column(name="lastname", nullable =false)
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password", nullable =false)
    private String password;
```

my persistence:

```
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.app.central.dao.pagination.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="./lucene/indexes"/>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate" />
        <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

is going to have an effect only when you save an entity using Java code.

What you are doing is inserting values directly into the database and your mysql database doesn't know that it's supposed to be generated any values for the id.

Comment: This. Plus, there might be missing an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)